# How to decode a text file by extracting alphabet characters and listing them into a message?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, python-3.6, decoding

So we were given an assignment to create a code that would sort through a long message filled with special characters (ie. [,{,%,$,*) with only a few alphabet characters throughout the entire thing to make a special message.

I've been searching on this site for a while and haven't found anything specific enough that would work.

I put the text file into a pastebin if you want to see it

https://pastebin.com/48BTWB3B

Anywho, this is what I've come up with for code so far

```
code = open('code.txt', 'r')
lettersList = code.readlines()
lettersList.sort()

for letters in lettersList:
    print(letters)
```

It prints the code.txt out but into short lists, essentially cutting it into smaller pieces. I want it to find and sort out the alphabet characters into a list and print the decoded message.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can do pretty easily with regex.

```
import re
with open('code.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    contents = filehandle.read()
letters = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", contents)
```

if you want to condense the list into a single string, you can use a join:

```
single_str = ''.join(letters)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's enough to submit, but for future reference, is there any way to have it print the letters without apostrophes surrounding them

Comment: You can use ''.join(letters). I've edited the answer above to include this.